# set the buttons at the bottom and yet full stretched in width in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i am trying to align button vertically and then want to set it to the bottom of the screen 
but as soon as i set its property `bottom:0` buttons go down but they dont stretched full in width.

wht i want is i want to set it to bottom and fullscreen in width.

[image]

here is my code

```
Ext.define("ca.view.cav",{
    extend:'Ext.Container',
    xtype:'cv',
    requires:['Ext.Button','Ext.Panel'],

    config:{
        bottom:0,
        defaults: {
            margin: '10 0 0 0'
        }   ,
        items:[{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'YES'
        },{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'NO'
        },{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'PROBABLY YES'
        },{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'PROBABLY NO'
        },{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'DON\'T KNOW'
        },{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'SKIP'
        }]
    }
});
```

and i am adding this container in to other panel as `xtype:cv`

Comment: What is the layout of the containing panel?  Can you post that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it works to just add `width: '100%'` to the config:

```
config:{
    bottom:0,
    width: '100%',
    defaults: {
        xtype:'button',
        margin: '10 0 0 0'
    },
    items:[{
        text:'YES'
    },{
        text:'NO'
    },{
        text:'PROBABLY YES'
    },{
        text:'PROBABLY NO'
    },{
        text:'DON\'T KNOW'
    },{
        text:'SKIP'
    }]
}
```

See here: http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/lWv9p/

Comment: they didnt maintain the center and because of that i have to set the `margin right` to `15` pixel to make it center

Comment: Did that fix the original issue, or are you still stuck?

Comment: yeah it fixed the issue but i hope in other devices it wont raise any problem in displaying buttons

Comment: Ok cool, hopefully there are no platform-specific issues... the hardest to debug :-/